# do something inside mainActivity whenever a push notification is received

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

In my app, whenever I receive a push notification, I will perform a check if my mainActivity is visible to the user to do something...

I have a static boolean value that is set `true` inside `onResume` of mainActivity, and `false` inside it's `onPause`.

What should I do inside the onMessage

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if(mainActivity == visible)
        //do something inside mainactivity.. change text inside edittext
    else 
        //do something else
}
```

any insights ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a fan of keeping static references to activities. I think they're a can of worms ready to explode on you. So you'll suggest an alternative to @TeRRo answer:

on your global BroadcastReceiver `onMessage` you'll send a `LocalBroadcast` that your activity will be listening to. Like this:

```
private static final String ACTION_PUSH_RECEIVED = "com.myapp.mypackage.action.pushReceived";
public static final IntentFilter BROADCAST_INTENT_FILTER = new IntentFilter(ACTION_PUSH_RECEIVED);

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_PUSH_RECEIVED);
    i.putExtra( ... add any extra data you want... )
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

and now we make the activity listen to it:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
     .registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, BroadcastReceiverClass.BROADCAST_INTENT_FILTER);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
      .unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        // read any data you might need from intent and do your action here

    }
}
```

Comment: my son, you are a genius. It is a shame you do not work for the biggest software firms in the plant.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, you should manage activities references. Add the name of the application in the manifest file:

```
 <application
   android:name=".MyApp"
   ....
 </application>
```

Your application class :

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
    }

    private Activity mCurrentActivity = null;
    public Activity getCurrentActivity(){
          return mCurrentActivity;
    }
    public void setCurrentActivity(Activity mCurrentActivity){
          this.mCurrentActivity = mCurrentActivity;
    }
}
```

Create a new Activity :

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {
protected MyApp mMyApp;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMyApp = (MyApp)this.getApplicationContext();
}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMyApp.setCurrentActivity(this);
}
protected void onPause() {
    clearReferences();
    super.onPause();
}
protected void onDestroy() {        
    clearReferences();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void clearReferences(){
    Activity currActivity = mMyApp.getCurrentActivity();
    if (currActivity != null && currActivity.equals(this))
        mMyApp.setCurrentActivity(null);
}
}
```

So, now instead of extending Activity class for your activities, just extend MyBaseActivity. Now, you can get your current activity from application or Activity context like that :

```
Activity currentActivity = ((MyApp)context.getApplicationContext()).getCurrentActivity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or why don't you use the Local broadcasts when you receive the push notification, and receive it in your activity, and do respective changes or actions.

And if they are UI intensive tasks, bind your activity to a service, and receive the push notification and perform the action in this service and use the result in the activity.